# Google Analytics - track downloaded files

Tags: google-analytics

Can Google Analytics track how many time a visitor clicks on a download link on my page. It will track how many people visit my page but I cannot see where it will tell me how many times people clicked on a link on that page.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not programming related may be better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend triggering a Google Analytics event once the user clicks on one of your download links.

You can do so using plain JavaScript:

```
ga('send', 'event', 'downloads', 'click', '/link-to-your-download-url');
```

More about Google Analytics events: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events

Or using Google Tag Manager:
https://mediacause.org/track-button-clicks-google-tag-manager/

Later, you can use this event to also great Goals in Google Analytics.